# If it possible to call REST apis directly from watchkit extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

If it is possible to call rest apis directly from Watchkit extension instead of using data sharing with companion app on Iphone.

My Query  is instead of calling Rest apis from Iphone app and transferring required data to watchkit, can we call Rest api directly from Interface controller of watchkit extension and utilise the same to render the UI of watch.

Please share the solution.

Comment: Its Possible since Watch OS2.

Answer (score 1):

its not possible with `WatchOS1`. you have to get data from `iPhone` only. But incase of `WatchOS2` you can because directly `WiFi` connectivity is there so you can connect and make request as well. Same as we have in `iOS` use `NSURLSession`